# cx_Freeze. How install service and execute script after install

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I wrote lets scripts for customer. In order not to install python and dependent packages, I packed all to 3 exe-file using cx-freeze. First  - winservice, who does most of the work. Second - settings wizard. Third - client for work with winservice. Faced to the task, need after installing the package (made using bdist_msi)  register the service in system, and run the wizard. How do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you don't have a certificate that's impossible.